# My website is available for some users, but for some it is not

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I've built a website (https://atpmetamorfoza.pl/) that loads properly for some users, but for some it just won't (around 10%). They see something like this: https://ibb.co/TtRjr1v.

**translation to English**:

 Page title - "website unavailable"

 Button - "go back"

 Title with link below - "visit the website".

Neither of these buttons work.
This page is built with wordpress + elementor + some custom css. Do you know where should I look for solution?

Comment: please make a [mre]

Comment: Perhaps those that fail, their client does not support TLS1.2 and/or Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman Ephemeral, at least, that's what I connect with.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. So there is nothing I can do with it? Like make it available for them?